# max value and another column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with 4 columns: products, company, revenue, units

Out of this I want distinct product names in one column, max, min, avg, std dev for revenue and units for that product is separate columns, and the company name that generated that max revenue for that product in another one. In the next I want the % of that revenue (out of the total revenue for that product).

I want this for every single product in the table. Any suggestion on how to do it?

I am able to get the max, min , avg, std dev and product but unable to get the name of that company corresponding to max revenue for that product.

Comment: The columns are typeless, no sample data available and you have trieed nothing ?

Comment: Could you add the relevant table information for this query?

Comment: i am new to sql and dont know quite a lot.
(products, company are varchar;
revenue, units are float)

Answer (score 1):

For the company corresponding to max revenue you can do something like this in your select statement.

```
select company from table where revenue =
(select max(revenue) from table where products = currentProduct)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ranking functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT products, company, revenue, units,
      MaxRevenue = MAX(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      MinRevenue = MIN(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      AvgRevenue = AVG(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      STDEV_Revenue = STDEV(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      MaxUnits = MAX(units) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      MinUnits = MIN(units) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      AvgUnits = AVG(units) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      STDEV_Units = STDEV(units) OVER (PARTITION BY products),
      Percent_Revenue = Max(Revenue)OVER (PARTITION BY products)/SUM(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY products),           
      ProductNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY products ORDER BY products)
    FROM dbo.TableName  
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE ProductNum = 1
```

Comment: awesome. it worked.
just two more columns: 
how much is that max revenue generated by that company as a % (out of the total revenue for that product).
and another column saying yes if it is >25 else no.
Thanks. Appreciate you help.

Comment: @Abhishek: Consider to accept the answer if your question is answered. You're  welcome.

Comment: @Abhishek: Then i have not understood the requirement. What %, can you give me at least the mathematical formula? Is it really that difficult now?

Comment: i tried to add a line:
 Percent_Revenue = (Max(Revenue)/sum(Revenue)) OVER (PARTITION BY products)
but it says incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'